# live, literate, lean programming with org-mode

Tags: org-mode

I would like to use `lean-mode` and `org-mode` together to write literate code that is also being parsed by the Lean server.

`lean-mode` (available on [melpa](https://melpa.org/#/lean-mode)) supports a live-coding style of interaction, illustrated here with flycheck-inline output.

[image]

I'm aware of Org Mode's sessions, which support a literate style for scripting languages.  Any suggestions about what would be involved in setting this up for Lean?

Here's a currently-not-working example, save as lll.org, notice that cursor-over on the `#check` line does nothing at present.

```
#+Title: Can I do literate live coding with lean?
Here I set up some imports.

#+begin_src lean
import topology.basic data.set.intervals
open real set
#+end_src

Now I want to use that information:

#+begin_src lean
#check (Icc (0:ℝ) 1)
#+end_src
```

## Summary of the challenge

I would like the collection of `lean` source code blocks within one org-mode file to operate as if they were different transcluded portions of one buffer in `lean-mode`. The Lean server should be active on all of these blocks, and the contents of the blocks should interoperate, e.g., so that `import` in an earlier block will make the imported definitions available in later blocks. How could this be arranged?

Comment: What's the question? What's not "working" about the example - what do you expect/want it to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: The desired behavior is: cursor-over the `#check` and have Lean print a result, via flycheck, as in the screenshot of from the lean-mode buffer above.  In the Org mode sample, my `lean` source code blocks use `lean-mode` for highlighting, but the Lean server is not invoked.

Comment: @JoeCorneli Org-mode puts the source blocks in a temporary buffer, selects the required major mode, and lets font-lock do its work. The text properties are then put onto the corresponding regions in the source block (see definition of `org-src-font-lock-fontify-block`). Flycheck uses overlays. I doubt that overlays survive the procedure of Org mode in any way. To get what you want you would have to define a `org-babel-execute:lean` for non-nil `:session` argument. Looks like there is currently [no such thing](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=%22org-babel-execute%3Alean%22).

Answer (score 0):

I've put together a package [ob-lean4](https://github.com/Maverobot/ob-lean4) that aims to assist in evaluating `lean4` source blocks within `org` files. It's a simple tool meant to facilitate the execution of `lean4` code within the context of org documents.

At present, the package doesn't offer support for `:session`. However, you can still engage in a form of literate programming to some extent using `:noweb`:

```
#+name: define-foo
#+begin_src lean4
  def foo : String := "Lean"
#+end_src

#+begin_src lean4 :noweb strip-export
  <<define-foo>>
  #eval foo
#+end_src
```